# MacVim-Like Find and Replace for gVim

Tags: vim, macvim

I know about the Vim find and Replace command, but I find MacVim's Find and Replace ( ⌘+F ) better compared to Vim's Native way of Finding Words. Is there a plugin for (g)Vim to assist ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used MacVim.

In gvim you can bring up the "Find and Replace" dialog like this:

```
:promptrepl
```

See if this mapping works for you:

```
:map <D-f> :promptrepl<cr>
```

(According to :h meta, <D- is the command key on Mac but I'm not sure if that would work as I can't test it)